# Using specific cipher for SSL/TLS in boost::asio

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio

I am implementing a mutual authentication where the server is using nodejs while client is using `boost::asio`. I was trying to work around by putting specific cipher and specific TLS version. I can force it to use the specific tls version, but how can I force boost::asio to work with specific ciphers. Here is my implementation code:

```
context_ptr ctx = websocketpp::lib::make_shared<boost::asio::ssl::context>(websocketpp::lib::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_client);
try {
        ctx->set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
                         boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
        ctx->set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_peer | 
        boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert);
        ctx->load_verify_file("ca_server.pem");
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Exception " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
SSL_set_cipher_list(ctx->native_handle(), "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384");
ctx->use_certificate_file("client.pem",
        boost::asio::ssl::context::file_format::pem);
ctx->use_private_key_file("client.key", 
        boost::asio::ssl::context::file_format::pem);
```

As you can see I want to use `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` cipher as authentication. Can anyone tell me what I should do to force it to use the specific cipher?

Note: My implementation of `SSL_set_cipher_list(ctx->native_handle(), "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384");` is wrong. So how can I make this work?

Comment: You're working with an SSL Context, not an SSL connection, so use `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` instead of `SSL_set_cipher_list`

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing the comment from @ottomeister, I realized that I was working on SSL context while I was using SSL connection. So I used, `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` instead of `SSL_set_cipher_list`, and it worked.